# How to debounce multiple clickable buttons

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash, debouncing

At present I am debouncing using the [lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) like so...

```
<Button
  onPress={_.debounce(
        () => {
               navigation.goBack()
              },
              500,
              {
                leading: true,
                trailing: false,
               }
   )}
   title="Back"
/>
```

Which works as expecte when I just click on one link, but if I click on two clickable areas like so... (see below gif) the following happens...

[image: issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move definition of debounced function from "render" method, like this:

```
export default class YourClassName extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.debouncedOnPressHandler = _.debounce(
      () => { navigation.goBack() },
      500,
      {
        leading: true,
        trailing: false,
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onPress={this.debouncedOnPressHandler} title="Back A" />
        <Button onPress={this.debouncedOnPressHandler} title="Back B" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```